# Columns are wrapping set to 50% even with border-box

Tags: html, css

I have the following code that I cant determine why the columns are wrapping, if I change the column width to 49% it doesn't wrap. I'm looking at it in the latest version of Chrome. I realize I could use float but I'm trying to determine why this doesn't work.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="column">
    aaaa
</div>
<div class="column">
    bbbbb
</div>
```

```
.column {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.container {
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h1tyLbbe/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to inline-block elements still taking whitespace into account.

If you do the following, it will work:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    aaaa
  </div><!--
--><div class="column">
    bbbbb
  </div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    aaaa
  </div><div class="column">
    bbbbb
  </div>
</div>
```